# Simple algebra question concernig the equation of a circle

Tags: algebra-precalculus

for some reason, I can't do the math. I have worked out that $(x^2+y^2-1)^2+4y^2=r^2((x+1)^2 + y^2)^2$ should be the circle $$\left(x-\dfrac {1+r^2}{1-r^2}\right)^2 + y^2= \left(\dfrac{2r}{1-r^2}\right)^2,$$ using some prior knowledge, however I can't prove it. Can someone help me on my way? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried expanding and multiplying things out first? Try writing here some of your working out!

Comment: It seems indeed lead to a circle, if $r \ne 1$.

Answer (score 1):

your first equation can be factorized into
$$- \left( {x}^{2}+{y}^{2}+2\,x+1 \right)  \left( {r}^{2}{x}^{2}+{r}^{2}
{y}^{2}+2\,{r}^{2}x+{r}^{2}-{x}^{2}-{y}^{2}+2\,x-1 \right) 
=0$$
the second factor is  equivalent to the equation
$$\left(x-\frac{1-r^2}{1+r^2}\right)^2+y^2=\left(\frac{2r}{1-r^2}\right)^2$$
if $$1-r^2\ne 0$$

Comment: change of sings needed in first term of final equation, many thanks.

Comment: Two comments : 1) You should correct the little typo that has been remarked by @Romanda de Gore : i.e. change the first fraction into its inverse 2) A more important one. A discussion should take place for the first factor ; this first factor could have added a whole circle of solutions. But as it can be reduced to $(x+1)^2+y^2$, it is zero iff $x=-1$ and $y=0$, it is a single point that is added.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the left-hand side as a quadratic equation in $y^2$:
$$ \begin{aligned}
(x^2+y^2-1)^2+4y^2 &= y^4 + 2y^2(x^2-1) + (x^2-1)^2 + 4 y^2 \\
  &= y^4 + 2y^2(x^2+1) + (x^2-1)^2 \\
 &= \left(y^2 + (x^2 + 1)\right)^2 + (x^2-1)^2 -  (x^2+1)^2 \\
 &= \left(y^2 + (x^2 + 1)\right)^2  - 4 x^2 \\
 &= \left(y^2 + (x + 1)^2\right)\left(y^2 + (x - 1)^2\right)
\end{aligned}$$
Then your equation becomes
$$
\left(y^2 + (x + 1)^2)\right)\left(y^2 + (x - 1)^2)\right)
 = r^2\left((x+1)^2 + y^2 \right)^2
$$
and it follows that 
$$
 y^2 + (x + 1)^2 = 0 
$$
which implies that $x=-1, y=0$, 
or the common factor can be cancelled:
$$
y^2 + (x - 1)^2 = r^2\left((x+1)^2 + y^2 \right) \\
\Longleftrightarrow
 (x^2+y^2+1)(1-r^2)-2x(1+r^2) = 0
$$
If $r=1$ then the solution is the line $x=0$ (i.e. the y-axis), otherwise 
the circle equation can now easily be derived.

Comment: @RomandadeGore: Thanks for fixing the sign error.